# Is there a way to get the song from my previous level to stop playing when the next one starts?

Tags: javafx

I'm making a Pong game with multiple levels and each level changes the background image and the audio

```
//runs image file only when scores = 0 and the previous score was NOT 0, preventing image converting and setting background every frame,
//as well as preventing the media player from updating every frame
//it also checks if the text that shows the current level is visible, if it is then it fades it out
if (Integer.parseInt(playerScore.getText()) == 0 && Integer.parseInt(aiScore.getText()) == 0 &&
    (previousPlayerScore != 0 || previousAiScore != 0)) {
        if (levelBackground.isVisible()) {
            levelBackground.setVisible(true);
            fadeOut.playFromStart();
        }
            
        convertImageFiles();
        convertAudioFiles();
}
```

They (as in the methods that convert and set image and audio) are both being called based on the current and previous score of the player and the ai as seen above and is checked every pulse of the animation timer. All of that is to show why I have my media player set up the way that it is. The comments in the code below explain whats happening so I won't explain further. My problem is that when I run the game everything works wonderfully...until the second level starts up and then the music from level 1 continues to play underneath the music for level 2 and so on through all of the levels.

```
MediaPlayer playMusic;
private void convertAudioFiles() {
    //gets the current level of gameplay
    int currentLevel = Integer.parseInt(level.getText());
    //iterates through audio file array
    for(int i = 0; i < audioArrayLength; i++) {
        //if the index + 1 is the current level
        if((i + 1) == currentLevel) {
            //then the current song is set to the correct index
            String currentSong = audioList[i];
            System.out.println(currentSong);
            //that song is turned into a file
            File musicFile = new File(currentSong);
            //and converted to media
            Media musicMedia = new Media(musicFile.toURI().toString());
            //passed into the media player
            playMusic = new MediaPlayer(musicMedia);
            //made to repeat if it ends
            playMusic.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    playMusic.seek(Duration.ZERO);
                }
            });
            //and played
            playMusic.play();
        }
         }
}
```

Is there a simple way to get the audio from the previous level to stop playing when it switches levels?

I was originally going to make a variable called "previousSong" and use that to shut if off, but the only way I could think to do that is to pass it to the mediaPlayer, however the currentSong is being passed in and creating a new one won't help anything. I tried to just do playMusic.stop() before I call playMusic.play(), but obviously that doesn't remove the song from the mediaPlayer, it only pauses briefly until play() is called and then both songs start playing. The only next thing I can think to do is use a List instead of an Array and remove the previous song if the level > 1, but I wanted to see if there's another solution before I do that. Any feedback would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I found the dispose method for Media Player. I initialized convertAudioFiles so that it would play the first song on the first level. Then in my changeLevel() method I check if the level is greater than 1 and call dispose to get rid of the previous song, then call convertAudioFiles so it sets up a fresh Media Player for the new song. Nice and simple :)

```
//runs image file only when scores = 0 and the previous score was NOT 0, preventing image converting and setting background every frame,
    //as well as preventing the media player from updating every frame
    //it also checks if the text that shows the current level is visible, if it is then it fades it out
    if (Integer.parseInt(playerScore.getText()) == 0 && Integer.parseInt(aiScore.getText()) == 0 &&
            (previousPlayerScore != 0 || previousAiScore != 0)) {
        if (levelBackground.isVisible()) {
            levelBackground.setVisible(true);
            fadeOut.playFromStart();
        }
        
        convertImageFiles();
        
        if(Integer.parseInt(level.getText()) > 1) {
            playMusic.dispose();
            convertAudioFiles();
        }
        
    }
```